# How to preLoad UICollectionVewCell?

Tags: ios, uicollectionviewcell, preload

I have all the UICollectionView dataSource, but the subViews in cell is not all the same.So need remove the old subViews and add the subViews when the cell showing again. Want to know any way to preload UICollectionViewCell or Make it more smoothly.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of "preloading" the cells, I would suggest subclassing `UITableViewCell` for each of your different types of cells, and adding the subviews in their `awakeFromNib` method. I would recommend against adding subviews in your `tableview:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method, you should just be updating the content (e.g. UILabel values).

If you add subviews inside `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath"` method, you will need to remove all of the subviews first. Otherwise if they are "reused" the subviews will be added on top of the existing ones.

Comment: eg: i have more then 100 images,webView and svg file in content. When add them to CollectionCell also lead fluency decline

Comment: The `UIView` class should already be added to the cell, you just want to update the content. E.g. for an image, the cell should already have a `UIImageView` and you should just be updating the `UIImageView`'s 'image' property (which is a `UIImage`).

Comment: I means that  I have A,B,C three Cells  for A it has 60 subviews,for B the count become 90 , and C only got 5 subViews

Comment: What I have explained still applies. You should not call `addSubview:` inside your `collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:` method (or any method that is called within).